# Fastest way to merge multiple pre-sorted arrays in one sorted array

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the fastest way to merge multiple pre-sorted arrays, into one sorted array, without duplicates.

For example:

```
const arrays = [
    [15, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50],
    [33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48],
    [37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]
];
```

Should output:

```
[15, 30, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 45, 48, 50]
```

In reality these arrays are much larger so I'm looking for a fast way to do this.

This question is about **performance** I'm aware it can be done in  with **concat** and **sort** in *O(n log(n))* but I'm looking for something *O(n)*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Or do it server side using PHP for example. Pretty easy that way.

Answer (score 1):

Untested. I don't think my code is optimal, but I currently don't see a better way to approach this.

Further small improvements might be:

- using ordinary `for` loops instead of `Array.prototype.reduce`
- removing arrays that reach a "done" status (instead of just flagging them as done)

---

```
console.time("Creation of arrays");
const arrays = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, row) => {
  return Array.from({ length: 100000 }, (_, i) => row + i);
});
console.timeEnd("Creation of arrays");

const createMergedArray = (arrays) => {
  console.time("Creation of toProcess");
  const toProcess = arrays.map((array, row) => {
    return { done: false, row, column: 0, array };
  });
  console.timeEnd("Creation of toProcess");

  const merged = [];

  while (toProcess.some(({ done }) => !done)) {
    const scan = toProcess.reduce(
      (acc, item) => {
        if (!item.done) {
          if (item.array[item.column] < acc.minimum) {
            acc.minimum = item.array[item.column];
            acc.rows = [item.row];
          } else if (item.array[item.column] === acc.minimum) {
            acc.rows.push(item.row);
          }
        }
        return acc;
      },
      { rows: [], minimum: Infinity }
    );

    merged.push(scan.minimum);

    scan.rows.forEach((row) => {
      const item = toProcess[row];
      while (item.array[item.column] === scan.minimum) {
        ++item.column;
      }
      item.done = item.array.length === item.column;
    });
  }

  return merged;
};

console.time("Merging");
const merged = createMergedArray(arrays);
console.timeEnd("Merging");

console.assert(
  merged.every((n, i, arr) => n > arr[i - 1] || 0 === i),
  "Unsorted or duplicates found"
);
```

You didn't mention the size of your arrays, so I used 1k rows with 100k columns.

If you pass your arrays (`number[][]`) to `createMergedArray`, it should give you:

- an array of unique numbers sorted ascendingly
- an idea of whether this approach is viable for the size of your data